# How to generate a 2D random vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, probability-density

I have a non-negative function `f` defined on a unit square `S = [0,1] x [0,1]` such that 
[image]

My question is, how can I use MATLAB to generate a 2D random vector from `S` according to the probability density function `f`?

Comment: I think unless your density is separable (so your two components are independent random variables), then this is a very difficult question. Do you know how to do this on paper? If you know the algorithm on paper,  you'll be able to code it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I unfortunately have no idea how to do that on paper. I just want to generate a random vecor according to some probability distribution, and all I was able to do was to use a pre-defined pdf funcions in Matlab

Comment: I'd approach that using [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835306/2586922), which, although in a different language, may serve as a guide

Comment: How would you discretize it? Given that this is a 2D matrix in MATLAB, it has to be discretized in some way. Given that, a simple solution would be to generate a 2D matrix with randn, and normalizing it (given that you know the sum of all the elements too) Since all the elements are normalized by a constant, the randomness would be retained. Am I missing something here, for this would satisfy the integral, right?

Comment: @akamath you're missing that OP needs a specific distribution:) "I have a non-negative function f", they just didn't tell us what it is. And they're right to do so: it doesn't really make a difference if it's not composed of independent ones.

Comment: @LuisMendo's suggestion sounds great. Choose a uniform random point, and see if another uniform random hits the (re-)normalized probability density (in the same way as you would do something "with p probability"). If it fits, keep the point, otherwise throw it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rejection Sampling**

The suggestion Luis Mendo made is very good because it applies to nearly all distribution functions. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835306/2586922) I wrote code for m.

An important point when using rejection sampling this way is that you must know the maximum of your pdf within the range. If you over-estimate the maximum your code will only run slower. If you under-estimate it it will create wrong numbers!

The idea is that you sample many uniform distributed points and accept depending on the probability density for the points.

```
pdf=@(x).5.*x(:,1)+3./2.*x(:,2);
maximum=2; %Right maximum for THIS EXAMPLE. 
%If you are unable to determine the maximum of your 
%function within the [0,1]x[0,1] range, please give an example.
result=[];
n=10;
while (size(result,1)<n)
    %1. sample random point:
    val=rand(1,2);
    %2. Accept with probability pdf(val)/maximum
    if rand<pdf(val)/maximum
        %append to solution
        result(end+1,:)=val;
    end
end
```

I know that this solution is not a fast implementation, but I wanted to start with an implementation as simple as possible to make sure that the concept of rejection sampling becomes clear.

Answer (score 1):

**ICDF**

Besides rejection sampling there is a different approach to address this issue on a more mathematical level, but you need to sit down and do some math first to end up with a better solution. For 1 dimensional distributions you typically sample using the ICDF (inverted cumulative density function) function simply using `ICDF(rand(n,1))` to get random samples.

If you manage to do the math, you could instead for your PDF function define two functions ICDF1 (ICDF for the first dimension) and ICDF2 (ICDF for the second dimension) in matlab.

The first ICDF1 would map unifrom random distributed samples to sample values for the first dimension of your random distribution.

The second ICDF2 would map the output if ICDF1 and uniform distributed samples to your intended solution.

Here is some matlab code assuming you already defined `ICDF1` and `ICDF2`

```
samples=ICDF1(rand(n,1));
samples(:,2)=ICDF2(samples,rand(n,1));
```

The great advantage of this solution is, that it does not reject any samples, being potentially much faster.